# PG Pool is not working inside Docker container

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, express, docker-compose

I am running a PERN application and currently trying to dockerize it. When I run the database as a container and the server and client locally I have no issues. However, when I containerize the server, client, and database respectively, I am unable to make requests. It results in 404 errors. This is the same behavior that occurs when I pass pool the wrong port or host. So I'm wondering if somehow I am giving the wrong host and/or port to pool or if I should change it when I containerize it.

This is the Pool Instance

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool

const pool = new Pool({
    user: 'docker',
    password: 'docker',
    host: "localhost",
    port: 4000,
    database: "docker"
})
```

This is part of the rest api in the server:

```
const express = require("express")
const router = express.Router()
const pool = require('../database/database.js')

router.get("/:login", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let loginReq = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(req.params.login))
        const user = await pool.query(
            "SELECT user_id,first_name,last_name,email FROM \"user\" where email = $1 and password = $2",
            [loginReq.email, loginReq.password]
        )
        if(user.rows.length) {
            res.json(user.rows[0])
        } else {
            throw new Error('User Not Found')
        }
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(404).json(err.message)
    }
})
```

This is each of my dockerfiles for my client, server, and database
Client:

```
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install --production
CMD ["npm","start"]
EXPOSE 3000
```

Server:

```
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install --production
CMD ["node","index.js"]
EXPOSE 5000
```

Database;

```
FROM postgres:15.1-alpine
COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:

  client:
    build: ./client
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    restart: unless-stopped

  server:
    build: ./server
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    restart: unless-stopped
  
  database:
    build: ./database
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=docker
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker
      - POSTGRES_DB=docker
      - PGPORT=4000
    volumes:
      - kurva:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: unless-stopped
  
volumes:
    kurva:
```

I don't understand why the behavior would be different between containerizing the server and running it locally when they all use the same ports. I have tried messing with the host and changing it to 0.0.0.0 but that did not help. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found that it was a host issue and I needed to change the host accessed in the pool to the service name. Additionally, I needed to add that the server depends on the database service.

This is the updated pg pool:

```
const pool = new Pool({
    user: 'docker',
    password: 'docker',
    host: "database",
    port: 4000,
    database: "docker"
})
```

This is the updated docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:

  client:
    build: ./client
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    restart: unless-stopped

  server:
    build: ./server
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - database
    restart: unless-stopped
  
  database:
    build: ./database
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=docker
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker
      - POSTGRES_DB=docker
      - PGPORT=4000
    volumes:
      - kurva:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: unless-stopped
  
volumes:
    kurva:
```